# HTML предотвращение искажения страницы

Tags: html, css, теги

Уважаемые специалисты, прошу помощи. Есть форма для комментариев, в ней разрешены некоторые html теги, такие как например `<b>` или `<i>`, но если кто-то из посетителей введет ошибочный вариант к примеру вставит в комментарий тег `<b>` (или другой), но не укажет закрывающий тег `</b>` то после вставки комментария вся страница растягивается и принимает искаженный вид. А возможно ли задать какой-нибудь параметр для родительского контейнера комментария, чтобы всё что в комментарии (в том числе html ошибки) не выходило за пределы контейнера. Если невозможно, то какие ещё есть способы? Проверять валидность кода проблематично, потому что среди разрешенный тегов есть и вложенные `table`, `th`, `tr`, `td` Благодарю.

Comment: Нужно обрабатывать на сервере введённый текст так, чтобы ошибочных вариантов не было. Нужно ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО проерять валидность кода, как бы вам этого ни хотелось избежать. А всё остальное решать уже потом

Comment: @andreymal своего рода валидатор?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, обязательно возьму на заметку, а есть ли какие-нибудь готовые решения валидатора на php?

Comment: Есть много реализаций для разных языков программирования, вроде должны неплохо гуглиться

Comment: Выводить пользовательский контент в `<iframe>`, и пусть юзеры там хоть пообкладываются корявым кодом.